# Changing Ellipses to user input RGB from the main class

Tags: java, swing, actionlistener, jcomponent

I've been searching everywhere to try to find how to change the colors `Ellipse2D.Double` and cannot seem to find my answer.

What I am trying to do is change the color of the `Ellipse` that is in the `JComponent` class, from the main class, the main class has 3 `JTextField`s where the user could enter RGB colors of the color they wish to change the ellipse to.

After the user clicks on a button, the `ActionListener` will then get the RGB values from the 3 `JTextField`s, and use those values as a color to change the ellipse in the `JComponent` program.

I am not sure how to start this. Should I declare `r` `g` and `b` attributes in the `JComponent` class, and then call it out in the main method? If so, how do I go about writing that?

Comment: Convert the RGB values to a [`java.awt.Color`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Color.html#Color-int-int-int-).  Either provide a method in you `JComponent` to set the color or use the components `setForeground` method if you're not using it for anything else, call `repaint` if you're managing the process yourself

Comment: We could use some code here.  MadProgrammer is talking about Graphis2d but if you meant skinning Swing or something else, the answer is totally different.

Comment: @markspace How else would you draw a `Ellipse2D.Double`?  Although I agree, some idea about what the OP is actually would be nice :P